Laravel run functions within a class sequentially
I want to run some functions so that when one function is finished, it runs the next function. Can you explain that?
Example: I want to run command Create a table and then run command migrate
like this image 
I tried to run it with events but it failed

Sounds like you're potentially looking for Laravel pipelines?

What do you mean by "like this image"? PHP itself does not run based on images

If you want to apply database changes, including creating tables, why not use migrations, they are already applied sequentially and are a core feature of Laravel.
If you want a bit more functionality more just create a small command with php artisan make:command YourCommandName and add all the things you need in sequence. You can call artisan commands from PHP with Artisan::call('your artisan command');. Although I would advise against running migrations in this way.

I want to do this through a front-end, as in the image
